# Why SQLite file exists but openDatabase gives an error?

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

I know that is a **repeated question**, but the old questions in *Stack Overflow* doesn't help me, because the things has changed.

**a)** I've copied my *SQLite* file `your.db` to my *asset* folder (read only) in *Android Studio*

**b)** In my app, I've copied from my asset to internal storage this way:

```
// Internal Storage Path: (/Data/User/0/*myapppath*/files)
val name="your.db"
val f = this.assets.open(name)
val SQLContent = f.bufferedReader().use{ it.readText()}
f.close()
val file = File(this.filesDir, name)
file.writeText(SQLContent)
```

**c)** I've checked if my file was really copied in my *Android* cell phone
The below code display show be display `OK`in a button. It did.

```
val file = File(this.filesDir, "your.db")
if (file.exists()) result="Ok" else result="Argh"I
```

**d)** Below the code for open my database (already stored in internal storage). However, it gives an error because the system has not found my database.

```
String DBPath  = file.getabsolutePath()
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DBPath,
    null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE)
```

I know the recommended *SQLite* database location is `...\databases` and not `...\files`, but even then, it does not make sense to give an error, since the file is physically there.

**UPDATE**:
Using [@commonsware](http://@CommonWare) comment, I've used *Device File Explorer*. So I've noticed that `SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase` is putting `corrupt` suffix in the file name  However, the error is

```
Error Code : 1294 (SQLITE_CANTOPEN_ENOENT)
Caused By : Specified directory or database file does not exist.
    (unknown error (code 1294): Could not open database)
```

**UPDATE 2**

Using [@commonsware](http://@CommonWare) accepted answer, I've replaced my code for copying files for a binary version.

Copy file from asset to internal storage:

```
val arq = this.assets.open(nome)
val file = File(this.filesDir, nome)
val saida = file.outputStream()
arq.copyTo(saida)
saida.close()
arq.close()
```

Now, it's works smoothly. I open the SQLite, run a query with cursor, scan the cursor, print the records, close the cursor and close the database. No additional error.

When I've used *Device File Explorer* tool (Menu *View*, *Tool Windows*) , it shows the privates  application files. When I copy the SQLite file back to my computer (Using `copy as` in the right button context menu) remains a failure during the copy. I think that this option try to  copy the file as a text, not as a binary file.

Comment: I recommend that you edit your question and provide your actual Kotlin code, along with the stack trace that you are getting. Beyond that, you might consider using the Device File Explorer in Android Studio to copy your database off of internal storage, then see if it is the exact same file that is in your assets. Perhaps there is an issue in how you are copying the data.

Comment: Ok, I will do it

Comment: I did'n know `Device File Explorer`. It's nice! I've discovered that Android put `corrupt` after `your.db`: `your.db.corrupt`

Comment: That's odd. I have not seen that behavior (adding the `corrupt` file extension) before. My guess is that SQLite does not like `your.db` for some reason, perhaps due to a bug in how you are copying the data. Try temporarily disabling your code that opens the database. Just make the copy, then use Device File Explorer to copy it to your development machine (right-click over the file and choose "Save As" from the context menu). See if it is the same as your asset.

Comment: I did it in Android Studio  It gives the following message when trying to copy: `Error saving file(s) to local system: Illegal char :> at index 143`.

Comment: I did my `db` file using `DB Browser SQLite`, I've discovered that when I just copy the file from asset, I cannot copy it anymore.  using `Device File Explorer`. It gaves the same message. I also try with small texts (not SQLites databases) and it works as a charm.

Comment: It works! I'm posting an update. However, it's curious because "Save As" in `Device File Explorer` keeps on failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had not noticed that you added your file-copying code in an edit.

```
val SQLContent = f.bufferedReader().use{ it.readText()}
```

SQLite databases are binary files, not text. Use `readBytes()` and `writeBytes()`, not `readText()` and `writeText()`.

Answer (score 1):

Assets will always be R/O, because they're part of the APK file. Here's an example method in Java, which returns a R/W handle (where `DATABASE_FILENAME` is the filename to open):

```
private static SQLiteDatabase db;
private Context mContext;

@Nullable
public SQLiteDatabase getDatabase() {

    /* attempting to return early */
    if(db != null && db.isOpen()) {
        return db;
    } else {
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        File path = this.mContext.getDatabasePath(Constants.DATABASE_FILENAME);
        if (path.exists()) {
            try {
                db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path.getAbsolutePath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            } catch (SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, path.getAbsolutePath() + " does not exist.");
        }
        return db;
    }
}
```

(Ordinary) the expected database directory is `/databases` and not `/files`. And if intending to open R/O from assets (eg. to import from there), then it would have to be flag `OPEN_READONLY` ...which is likely the cause for `SQLITE_CANTOPEN_ENOENT` in combination with flag `OPEN_READWRITE` and a R/O resource; calling `db.close()` twice is also something to consider for data import. I merely use `db.execSQL()` to insert ...which is a reliable alternative to messing around with database files - and one can even insert localized strings. binary copy dearly fails at content localization.

Comment: I think that is a recommendation, it is not mandatory. How my database is very simple i don't mind if do a little bit different.

Comment: @PauloBuchsbaum another possible cause may be not using `res/raw` for the source file; the other directories in there are being processed by AAPT2, not copied 1:1. there's generally four options: a) import from file, b) copy the file, c) run SQL, d) generate the scheme with `Room`.